# Mac user is able to login, but sudo doesn't work

Tags: macos, mac, passwords, sudo, active-directory

We have a strange problem with a Mac OSX El Capitan. The Mac is joined to an active directory domain and the user is able to log in with his domain password.

In the settings, the user is listed and has the "allow user to administer this computer" checkox ticked.

When the user tries to use any command the requires elevation, the Mac will prompt for the password, but the domain password is not accepted. The same happens when he uses sudo from the terminal. We are 100% sure that the typed in password is correct. We have already reset the password in the active directory, and the user can use this new password for logging into his computer.

Does anyone have any idea why the password is not accepted when trying to elevate permissions? We have countless other computers running in the same configuration that do not have this problem.